# TypeError: <class> is not a constructor, but different class works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

I'm getting an error where I can instantiate one class but not the other, but as far as I can see, there's no difference between the two. I'm new to nodejs and not sure what I'm doing wrong. All files shown below are siblings in a directory.

/********** exampleClass.js ********/

```
const classOne = require("./classOne");
const classTwo = require("./classTwo")


module.exports = class exampleClass {

    method() {

        // works fine
        const classOneInstance = new classOne();

        const classTwoInstance = new classTwo(); // gives error 'TypeError: classTwo is not a constructor' UNLESS I require classTwo in the method. Doesn't matter if this goes before or after classOneInstance

    }
}
```

/********** classOne.js *****************/

```
module.exports = class classOne {

}
```

/************classTwo.js ****************/

```
const classOne = require("./classOne");
const exampleClass = require("./exampleClass");


module.exports = class classTwo {

    method() {

        const exampleClassInstance = new exampleClass();
        exampleClassInstance.method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show all the code instead of just commenting it out: it might be the problem.

Comment: @AndrewLi I just edited it. That's literally all the code

Comment: You do realize you've got circular references right? There's something wrong with design if that's what you have.

Comment: Yes, I was stupid. Put that as an answer and I'l accept it @AndrewLi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I was calling exampleClass from classTwo, and then exampleClass called classTwo, it was a circular reference which gave that error. Thanks to @AndrewLi